# How to update serialized data on valid?

Tags: django

I have two models, `BookTicket` and `Ticket`.

```
class BookTicket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    booking_ref = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)

class Ticket(models.Model):
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show)
    booking_ref = models.ForeignKey(BookTicket)
```

And this is the data from the client side

```
[
    {u'seat': 49, u'user': 3, u'show': 2}, 
    {u'seat': 50, u'user': 3, u'show': 2}
]
```

What I would like to do is, if the serialized `is_valid`, then create a new booking object, and update that object as the `booking_ref` for the all tickets data.

```
def buy_ticket(request):
    serialized = TicketSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
    if serialized.is_valid():
        ...
        b = BookTicket.objects.create(user=request.user)
        ...
        ... update all of the data's booking_ref with newly created booking instance i.e., b
        ...
        serialized.save()
        return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `b` as argument of `save` method ([docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save)). This will add `booking_ref` for new tickets:

```
serialized = TicketSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
if serialized.is_valid():
    b = BookTicket.objects.create(user=request.user)
    serialized.save(booking_ref=b)
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you